# How does SIP server work?

Tags: android, sip, voip

I want to create VoIP SIP app on Android. In Android example, I found SipDemo project, and it's SIP client. But I don't know how client from SipDemo can register and connect to SIP server such as Asterisk or Yate? And how does SIP server work?
Thank you everyone.

Answer (score -2):

Uff, where to start? well the very first thing is to read [RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261).

SIP (*session initiation protocol*) is a way to *initiate a session* between two elements:

1. A UAC (*user agent client*)
2. And a UAS (*user agent server*)

... both are just phones, the distinction being really on who initiates the session establishment.

In that task, they are assisted by two additional functions:

1. A SIP Registrar. This is an entity that knows how to map SIP addresses to the IP and port where the UAS is listening.
2. A SIP Proxy. This is the entity that routes requests between the UAC and UAS, potentially through several SIP Proxies, eventually querying the registrar to contact the UAS.

Things can be more complicated, if for example we're talking about an IMS environments with their HSS, P/I/S-CSCF or Application Servers.